# No configuration file found and no installation code available. Exiting

Tags: installation, configuration

I am getting the following error when I try to access my Wordpress website. It was working quite fine previously. Could anyone help me on this.

> No configuration file found and no installation code available. Exiting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Wordpress there will be a default **wp-config.php** file and I think this has been missing from your package. Please Check if it is there, else create a new one with file name **wp-config.php** and Place the following code in it with appropriate Database Credentials.

```
<?php
// ** MySQL settings ** //
define('DB_NAME', 'DATABASE-NAME');    // The name of the database
define('DB_USER', 'DATABASE-USERNAME');     // Your MySQL username
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'DATABASE-PASSWORD'); // ...and password
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');  
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

// You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each a unique prefix
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';   // Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!

// Change this to localize WordPress.  A corresponding MO file for the
// chosen language must be installed to wp-content/languages.
// For example, install de.mo to wp-content/languages and set WPLANG to 'de'
// to enable German language support.
define ('WPLANG', '');

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__).'/');
require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-settings.php');
?>
```

Comment: ok i will check that and revert back

Comment: thanks uzair that one solved my issue thanks alot....!You are awesome....!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a wp_config.php file, and you can viw the home page but not the internal pages, try changing the Permalinks style.

This can sometimes fix issues with .htaccess settings.